# how to bypass form filling of asp form with direct http request

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net, web

As i guess, filling an asp form will finally pack all data filled and make a post request to a certain url to update the data. How could i bypass the form filling efforts and pass the required values with other external methods, e.g via making http request. How could i investigate what have to pass and what the destination url of the form is.

I have tried to look into the html scripts but could only know the web will trigger a javascript when pressing the button. However, i have no clue on the next step.

Thanks!!

Comment: What is the code that you have tried so far? C# has multiple different ways of doing POST and PUT requests to web services. I'm not sure we can accurately answer with no idea what steps have been taken already. http://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/

Comment: This is a very broad question with no specific answer.  That said, you already have everything you need in your browser when you're on the site in question and "view source".  We're not going to be able to teach you enough Javascript and general web development skills to answer this question.

Comment: @VictorProcure OP is asking about posting a form from a web page - not how to do it with C#.  In fairness, that shouldn't even be tagged.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. However, as i am new to http request. What i learnt before is just simply posting data to a php in an external server. But i dont know how to track what the http request the web made when submitting the form. One of the possible way seems to make a c# project and pretend to be the web and directly post the data. So, how could i find what the web is posting, like the url, datas. Or what is the name of topic for me to investigate further? Thanks!

Comment: Are you able to post data correctly and get a response?  If so you can find all the information you need by learning how to use the developer tools in whichever web browser you use.  There are also tools like Fiddler that will capture all web traffic so you can inspect it.

Comment: I would like to understand how the web performed so that i can do the similar thing on c# or other platforms

Comment: Then research is your answer - not Stack Overflow.  Stack Overflow is for problems like *"Here is some code.  I want it to do X but it does Y."*

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to accomplish that:

One of easiest possible solutions is to send AJAX request via JQuery.

First you have to launch your function, you can do it either by binding it to button:

```
<input type="button" value="Text" onclick="mySubmit()" />
```

or by binding it to your submit action:

```
$(document).ready(() => {
  $("form").submit(mySubmit(e));
});
```

In second case you need to pass `e` argument to stop default submit. You do it by adding `e.preventDefault()` at the beginning of `mySubmit(e)` function.

Now, in `mySubmit()` you can do whatever you need with that form data. First you retrieve it with jQuery selector

```
var formArray = $("form").serializeArray()
```

and then you can do whatever you need to do with its data. To retrieve one element of this array you can use `find()` function, like:

```
form.find(x=>x.name === "propertyName")
```

After you do all you need to fill this form, send AJAX request this way:

```
$.ajax({
        url: form.attr("action"),
        type: form.attr("method"),
        data: JSON.stringify(form)
    });
```